# Regex (java) help

Tags: java, regex, split

How do I split this comma+quote delimited String into a set of strings:

```
String test = "[\"String 1\",\"String, two\"]"; 
String[] embeddedStrings = test.split("<insert magic regex here>");
//note: It should also work for this string, with a space after the separating comma: "[\"String 1\", \"String, two\"]";    

assertEquals("String 1", embeddedStrings[0]);
assertEquals("String, two", embeddedStrings[1]);
```

I'm fine with trimming the square brackets as a first step. But the catch is, even if I do that, I can't just split on a comma because embedded strings can have commas in them.
Using Apache StringUtils is also acceptable.

Comment: So you're output will always be 'String 1' and 'String, two'? I guess you have comma delimited, quote enclosed fields. Are the quotes optional or required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove `[\"`  from the start of the outer string and `\"]` from the end of it
to become:

```
      String test = "String 1\",\"String, two";
```

You can use:

```
     test.split("\",\"");
```

Comment: I ended up going with this. It's ugly, as most regex is, but it's effective and my options are limited:
        String noBrackets = StringUtils.substringBetween(test, "[\"", "\"]");
        String[] results = noBrackets.split("\",[ ]*\"");

Answer (score 3):

You could also use one of the many open source small libraries for parsing CSVs, e.g. [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) or [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/).

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely fragile and should be avoided, but you could match the string literals.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"((?:[^\"]+|\\\\\")*)\"");

String test = "[\"String 1\",\"String, two\"]";
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
ArrayList<String> embeddedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    embeddedStrings.add(m.group(1));
}
```

The regular expression assumes that double quotes in the input are escaped using `\"` and not `""`. The pattern would break if the input had an odd number of (unescaped) double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force method, some of this may be pseudocode and I think there's a fencepost problem when setting currStart and/or String.substring(). This assumes that brackets are already removed.

```
boolean inquote = false;
List strings = new ArrayList();
int currStart=0;
for (int i=0; i<test.length(); i++) {
  char c = test.charAt(i);
  if (c == ',' && ! inquote) {
    strings.add(test.substring(currStart, i);
    currStart = i;
  }
  else if (c == ' ' && currStart + == i)
    currStart = i; // strip off spaces after a comma
  else if (c == '"')
    inquote != inquote;
}
strings.add(test.substring(currStart,i));
String embeddedStrings = strings.toArray();
```